# BCryptEncrypt returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER on AES-GCM

Tags: delphi, winapi, cryptography, aes, cng

I'm trying to implement AES GCM using [CNG Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal) and stuck on last step.

---

**Disclaimer: Do not be afraid with that amount of code, most of it is just WinAPI functions and structures declaration, scroll down to actual question text. Thanks.**

---

Uses:

```pascal
uses System.Classes, Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils;
```

Interface section *(**NOT** everything is correct here **(see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816507/10824407))**, added just in case if somebody will try to reproduce)*:

```pascal
type
  BCRYPT_KEY_LENGTHS_STRUCT = packed record
    dwMinLength, dwMaxLength, dwIncrement: ULONG;
  end;
  BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTHS_STRUCT = BCRYPT_KEY_LENGTHS_STRUCT;
  
  BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_HEADER = packed record
    dwMagic, dwVersion, cbKeyData: ULONG;
  end;
  
  BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO = packed record
    cbSize, dwInfoVersion: ULONG;
    pbNonce: Pointer;
    cbNonce: ULONG;
    pbAuthData: Pointer;
    cbAuthData: ULONG;
    pbTag: Pointer;
    cbTag: ULONG;
    pbMacContext: Pointer;
    cbMacContext, cbAAD: ULONG;
    cbData: ULONGLONG;
    dwFlags: ULONG;
  end;

const
  BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE = 'ChainingMode';
  BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM = 'ChainingModeGCM';
  BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH = 'AuthTagLength';
  BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB = 'KeyDataBlob';
  //
  BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO_VERSION = $00000001;
  //
  BCrypt = 'Bcrypt.dll';

function BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(var phAlgorithm: Pointer;
  pszAlgId: PWideChar; pszImplementation: PWideChar; dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD;
  stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptSetProperty(hObject: Pointer; pszProperty: PWideChar;
  pbInput: Pointer; cbInput: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall;
  external BCrypt;
function BCryptGetProperty(hObject: Pointer; pszProperty: PWideChar;
  pbOutput: Pointer; cbOutput: ULONG; var pcbResult: ULONG; dwFlagd: ULONG)
  : DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlgorithm: Pointer; var phKey: Pointer;
  pbKeyObject: Pointer; cbKeyObject: ULONG; pbSecret: Pointer; cbSecret: ULONG;
  dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptGenRandom(phAlgorithm: Pointer; pbBuffer: Pointer;
  cbBuffer: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptExportKey(hKey: Pointer; hExportKey: Pointer;
  pszBlobType: PWideChar; pbOutput: Pointer; cbOutput: ULONG;
  var pcbResult: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptEncrypt(hKey: Pointer; pbInput: Pointer; cbInput: ULONG;
  pPaddingInfo: Pointer; pbIV: Pointer; cbIV: ULONG; pbOutput: Pointer;
  cbOutput: ULONG; var pcbResult: ULONG; dwFlags: ULONG): DWORD; stdcall;
function BCryptDestroyKey(hKey: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
function BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm: Pointer; dwFlags: ULONG)
  : DWORD; stdcall; external BCrypt;
```

Implementation:

```pascal
function GetCryptoRandomBytes(var Buffer: TBytes; Size: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  Status: DWORD;
  hAlgorithm, hKey: Pointer;
begin
  result := False;
  Status := BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm,
    BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM, nil, 0);
  if Status = 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Buffer, Size);
    Status := BCryptGenRandom(hAlgorithm, Buffer, Size, 0);

    if Status = 0 then
      result := True;
  end;
  BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0)
end;


function AESGCMEncrypt(var Data, AAD, Key, IV, Tag, EncryptedData: TBytes;
  KeyLength: DWORD = 32): Boolean;
const
  AES_GCM_IV_LENGTH = 12;  // nonce
var
  Status, KeyLen, BytesDone, BlockLength: DWORD;
  hAlgorithm, hKey: Pointer;
  TagLength: BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTHS_STRUCT;
  KeyDataBlobHeader: BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_HEADER;
  AuthCiferModeInfo: BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO;
  KeyTemp: TBytes;
begin
  result := False;
  BytesDone := 0;

  Status := BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm,
    BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, nil, 0);
  if Status = 0 then
  begin
    KeyLen := Length(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM);
    Status := BCryptSetProperty(hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
      PChar(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), BytesDone, 0);

    if Status = 0 then
    begin
      KeyLen := SizeOf(TagLength);
      Status := BCryptGetProperty(hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH,
        @TagLength, KeyLen, BytesDone, 0);

      if (Status = 0) and GetCryptoRandomBytes(KeyTemp, KeyLength) then
      begin
        Status := BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlgorithm, hKey, nil, 0, KeyTemp,
          KeyLength, 0);

        if Status = 0 then
        begin
          Status := BCryptExportKey(hKey, nil, BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB, nil, 0,
            KeyLen, 0);  // Get size

          if Status = 0 then
          begin
            SetLength(KeyTemp, KeyLen);
            Status := BCryptExportKey(hKey, nil, BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB, KeyTemp,
              KeyLen, KeyLen, 0);

            if Status = 0 then
            begin
              Move(KeyTemp[0], KeyDataBlobHeader, SizeOf(KeyDataBlobHeader));
              SetLength(Key, KeyDataBlobHeader.cbKeyData);
              Move(KeyTemp[SizeOf(KeyDataBlobHeader)], Key[0],
                KeyDataBlobHeader.cbKeyData);

              if GetCryptoRandomBytes(IV, AES_GCM_IV_LENGTH) then
              begin
                SetLength(Tag, TagLength.dwMaxLength);
                SetLength(EncryptedData, Length(Data)); // same length as source

                FillChar(AuthCiferModeInfo, SizeOf(AuthCiferModeInfo), #0);
                with AuthCiferModeInfo do
                begin
                  cbSize := SizeOf(AuthCiferModeInfo);
                  dwInfoVersion := BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO_VERSION;
                  pbNonce := IV;
                  cbNonce := AES_GCM_IV_LENGTH;
                  pbAuthData := AAD;
                  cbAuthData := Length(AAD);
                  pbTag := Tag;
                  cbTag := TagLength.dwMaxLength;
                end;

                KeyLen := Length(Data);
                Status := BCryptEncrypt(hKey, Data, KeyLen, @AuthCiferModeInfo,
                  nil, 0, EncryptedData, KeyLen, BytesDone, 0);
                  
                // Status = $C000000D = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

                if Status = 0 then
                  result := True
                else // Free all buffers
                begin
                  SetLength(Tag, 0);
                  SetLength(EncryptedData, 0);
                  SetLength(Key, 0);
                  SetLength(IV, 0);
                end;
              end
              else // Free all buffers
              begin
                SetLength(Key, 0);
                SetLength(IV, 0);
              end;
            end;
          end;
          BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        end;
        SetLength(KeyTemp, 0); // Free buffer
      end;
    end;
  end;
  BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);
end;
```

---

**Here actual question started**

I know it seems like there's a lot of code, but it's not the point. All works perfectly except last [`BCryptEncrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt) call which returns `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` (`0xC000000D`).

I've tried to follow docs, so I have no idea which of parameters doesn't fit. I guess issue is in [`BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info) structure, but can't find it.

So, *dear WinAPI Gods*, could you please point me what have I done wrong? I would really appreciate any help: links, debugigng ideas, etc.

Here's how I call this function:

```pascal
var
  Key, Tag, IV, AAD, Data, EncData: TBytes;
  src, add_data: string;
begin
  src := 'test_string_1234';
  add_data := '12345678';
  Data := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(src);
  AAD := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(add_data);

  AESGCMEncrypt(Data, AAD, Key, IV, Tag, EncData);
end;
```

*P.S. I'm using Delphi 10.3 Community.*

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried to check how this API works in C++ and ... just look. Here is `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure (*copied from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info)*):

```cpp
typedef struct _BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO {
  ULONG     cbSize;         // 4 bytes
  ULONG     dwInfoVersion;  // 4 bytes
  PUCHAR    pbNonce;        // 8 bytes (on x64)
  ULONG     cbNonce;        // 4 bytes
  PUCHAR    pbAuthData;     // 8 bytes (on x64)
  ULONG     cbAuthData;     // 4 bytes
  PUCHAR    pbTag;          // 8 bytes (on x64)
  ULONG     cbTag;          // 4 bytes
  PUCHAR    pbMacContext;   // 8 bytes (on x64)
  ULONG     cbMacContext;   // 4 bytes
  ULONG     cbAAD;          // 4 bytes
  ULONGLONG cbData;         // 8 bytes
  ULONG     dwFlags;        // 4 bytes
} BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO, *PBCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO;
```

Let's calculate total size: `4 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 4 + 8 + 4 = 72`. **BUT** `sizeof(BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO)` returns `88`. I have no clue, where 16 additional bytes came from. Could somebody explain me??

Comment: @RbMm, my data is 16 bytes long, which have to be multiple to 16. Also about `BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING`, quote from docs: *"This flag must not be used with the authenticated encryption modes (AES-CCM and AES-GCM)."*. AES is symmetric algorithm, so how can I use asymmetric key pair? Or how can I not pass `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`, when it required in docs? Sorry, don't clearly understand your message.

Comment: It seems related to [Padding and Alignment of Structure Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/padding-and-alignment-of-structure-members?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, It's sick, but I found a soluction. Just replaced `packed record` with `record`, I think delphi compiler somehow fix that padding internally.

Comment: for example `pbAuthData` must be aligned on 8 bytes on x64, so between `cbNonce` and `pbAuthData` will be pad 4 bytes which you not take to account. and so on

Comment: so here 3 padding of 4 bytes - (cbNonce, pbAuthData) (cbAuthData, pbTag )(cbTag,pbMacContext) and size of structure must be multiple of it aligned. structure aligned on 8 bytes. so must be pad 4 bytes at the and too. +4*4=16 bytes

Comment: @RbMm, yes, thanks to *Rita* I've found what was wrong. Thank you for clarification anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BCryptEncrypt() call which returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
> (0xC000000D).

```
BCryptEncrypt(keyHandle, pt, sizeof(pt), &authInfo, NULL, 0, ct, sizeof(ct), &bytesDone, 0);
```

Show values passed in above function that work for me, then you can compare with yours.

[image]

**Update:**

After comparing, it turns out that the size (`cbSize`) of `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure is wrong calculated. It expects `88` but pass in `72`. It is related to "[Padding and Alignment of Structure Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/padding-and-alignment-of-structure-members?view=msvc-160)".

> [cbSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info#members)
>
> The size, in bytes, of this structure. Do not set this field directly.
> Use the [BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcrypt_init_auth_mode_info) macro instead.

**Small update**

To let code from question work properly change `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO = packed record` to `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO = record`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght What's the value of `dwFlags` paremeter of `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght You can check [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/86872/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-a-non-multiple-of-16-byt.html). The first call of `BCryptEncrypt` successfully.

Comment: I have no idea what am I doing wrong, but [literally same code](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/88051/view.html), just implemented on delphi returns error, pure madness. The worst is that whole structure (*except size and version*) is just pointers to data and size of that data, so it can't be wrong.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Have you tried set `pPaddingInfo` to `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, same error message. But I can see logic in that, GCM mode expect that structure. .... Installing Visual Studio, want to check this code natively in C++.

Comment: @OlvinRoght But it helps. So the error is not in this structure. Continue to check other parameters. This works for me: `BCryptEncrypt(keyHandle, pt, sizeof(pt), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &bytesDone, 0);` So left are second and third ones.

Comment: Surprisingly, this returns 0 (success). But when I add buffer to output - failed.

Comment: @OlvinRoght If you mean [`pbOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt), what's the return value of `pcbResult` when `pbOutput` set to `NULL`.

Comment: It's `16` which is exactly same as input length.