# C++ Bcrypt "BCryptDecrypt" returns "0xc000000d"

Tags: c++, bcrypt, aes-gcm

This is a repost, as my last one was too much, so I'm going to make it simple.

On the second call to `BCryptDecrypt()`, it fails returning `0xc000000d`. I am aware the code is bad and has many points of failure, but in my test none of those points failed.

I compared this to the C# version of the code that works, debuggers for both show they have all the same values for buffers / returned values just fails at the second call of `BCryptDecrypt()`.

My goal is to decrypt an Encrypted / Ciphered Text Block using a Key from that Block. Uses AES-GCM I want to use ONLY Bcrypt. It is possible as I have a C# version, I don't want to import extra libs, like OpenSSL.

If you want to try, here is the Base64 Encoded Key, you need to decode from base64, skip 5 bytes for `"DPAPI"`, then call to `CryptUnprotectData()`.

The value to be Decrypted / Decoded is (Base64 + AES-GCM):

> RFBBUEkBAAAA0Iyd3wEV0RGMegDAT8KX6wEAAADeBU2aOO6lQ73DYvrL8hhAAAAAAAIAAAAAABBmAAAAAQAAIAAAALXsSijRcSAV3S8PSvKZXUddV2eE+nv5xtn8JaePfpjrAAAAAA6AAAAAAgAAIAAAAJ96r2xQdEkkXuEaGEcVG24QJSKXG9s14w/yS8gdO/CxMAAAABs64+DTxkrQnkH1e3d0w/tOPIRrB1OBPrw4uxX4Q0AfYv6pyMZKXchhn1qol8bMvUAAAADisCS/m6UBBzMxVLBgpCvQsGIa6hYT/J8NGZuFOqydlstlxLBL2K8tCX550IoHtwuEA8EGJTxMsW6wh/0H3VRn

(this is my password/key for my CTF / Project, I allow it to be decrypted / decoded)

Code to decrypt:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> AesGcm::DecryptWithKey(
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& ciphered_data, 
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& key)
{
    //Create the IV
    std::vector<uint8_t> iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // IV 12 bytes
    std::copy(ciphered_data.begin() + 3, ciphered_data.begin() + 15, iv.begin());

    //Create Buffer witth Ciphered Data only
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(ciphered_data.size() - 15);
    std::copy(ciphered_data.begin() + 15, ciphered_data.end(), buffer.begin());

    //Create TAG
    std::vector<uint8_t> tag(16);
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(buffer.size() - tag.size());

    //Last 16 bytes for tag
    std::copy(buffer.end() - 16, buffer.end(), tag.begin());

    //encrypted password
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - tag.size(), data.begin());
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> aad(0);//Just an Empty AAD param

    return Decrypt(key, iv, aad, data, tag);
}

std::vector<uint8_t> AesGcm::Decrypt(
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& key,
          std::vector<uint8_t>& iv,
          std::vector<uint8_t>& aad,
          std::vector<uint8_t>& cipher_text,
          std::vector<uint8_t>& authTag)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> p_text(0);
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg;

    if (!OpenAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, MS_PRIMITIVE_PROVIDER, BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM))
        return p_text;
    
    auto key_sz_bts = AesGcm::GetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH);
    if (key_sz_bts.empty() || key_sz_bts.size() != 4) {
        std::cout << "Inavlid PropertySize::" << key_sz_bts.size() << std::endl;
        if (hAlg) BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0x0);
        return p_text;
    }

    auto blob_vec = AesGcm::CreateBlob(key);
    auto key_sz = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(key_sz_bts.data());

    if (blob_vec.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Invalid Blob Size::" << blob_vec.size() << std::endl;
        if (hAlg) BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0x0);
        return p_text;
    }

    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hBck;
    std::vector<uint8_t> kdata_buffer(key_sz);
    std::vector<uint8_t> mac(authTag.size());

    DWORD dwStatus =
        BCryptImportKey(hAlg, NULL, BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB, &hBck, kdata_buffer.data(), kdata_buffer.size(), blob_vec.data(), blob_vec.size(), 0x0);

    if (FAILED(dwStatus)) {
        std::cout << "BCryptImportKey(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]" << std::endl;
        if (hBck) BCryptDestroyKey(hBck);
        if (hAlg) BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0x0);
        return p_text;
    }

    //Create the AUTH Struct
    BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO authInfo;
    authInfo.dwInfoVersion = 0x00000001;
    authInfo.pbNonce = iv.data();
    authInfo.cbNonce = iv.size();
    authInfo.pbAuthData = aad.data(); //aad.data();
    authInfo.cbAuthData = aad.size();//aad.size();
    authInfo.pbTag = authTag.data();
    authInfo.cbTag = authTag.size();
    authInfo.pbMacContext = mac.data();
    authInfo.cbMacContext = mac.size();//authTag.size();
    authInfo.cbAAD = 0;
    authInfo.cbData = 0;
    
    //authInfo.cbSize = sizeof(BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO);
    authInfo.cbSize = sizeof(authInfo);

    auto authtg_tg_bts = AesGcm::GetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH);

    //Get Auth Tag Size
    auto atag_size = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&authtg_tg_bts[4]);
    std::vector<uint8_t> iv_data(atag_size);
    DWORD ptext_size = 0;

    //Decrypt Data now
    dwStatus = BCryptDecrypt(
        hBck, cipher_text.data(), cipher_text.size(), &authInfo, iv_data.data(), iv_data.size(), nullptr, 0, &ptext_size, 0x0);

    if (FAILED(dwStatus) || ptext_size <= 0) {
        std::cout << "BCryptDecrypt2(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]::SIZE::" << ptext_size << std::endl;
        goto end;
    }

    p_text.resize(ptext_size);

    //Fails at this Second Call
    dwStatus = BCryptDecrypt(
        hBck,
        cipher_text.data(),
        cipher_text.size(),
        &authInfo,
        iv_data.data(),
        iv_data.size(), p_text.data(), p_text.size(), &ptext_size, 0x0);

    if (FAILED(dwStatus)) {
        std::cout << "BCryptDecrypt2(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]" << std::endl;
        goto end;
    }

end:
    if (hBck) BCryptDestroyKey(hBck);
    if (hAlg) BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0x0);
    return p_text;
}
```

"Unprotect" decoded Base64 Key:

```cpp
//encryptedData is the Decoded Base64 Data skipped 5 Bytes
DATA_BLOB DataIn;
DataIn.cbData = encryptedData.size();
DataIn.pbData = (BYTE*)encryptedData.data();//const_cast<uint8_t*>(encryptedData.data());

auto num = 1u;
if (dwFlags == 1) {
    num |= 4u;
}

DATA_BLOB DataOut;
if (!CryptUnprotectData(&DataIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, num, &DataOut))
    throw std::exception("CryptUnprotectData failed.");
    
std::vector<uint8_t> result(DataOut.pbData, DataOut.pbData + DataOut.cbData);
LocalFree(DataOut.pbData);
```

Rest of the code (incase I am doing something wrong somewhere else)

```
std::vector<uint8_t> AesGcm::CreateBlob(const std::vector<uint8_t>& key) {
    //Create KeyBlob
    std::vector<uint8_t> key_bloc_vec(4 * 3 + key.size());

    //Write The MAGIC
    DWORD kbm = BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_MAGIC;
    //uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&kbm);
    std::memcpy(key_bloc_vec.data(), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&kbm), sizeof(int));

    //Write 0x1
    DWORD rnd = 0x1;
    //uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&rnd);
    std::memcpy(key_bloc_vec.data() + 4, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&rnd), sizeof(int));

    //Write Size
    DWORD ksz = key.size();
    std::memcpy(key_bloc_vec.data() + 8, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ksz), sizeof(int));

    //Write KEY
    std::memcpy(key_bloc_vec.data() + 12, key.data(), key.size());

    return key_bloc_vec;
}


bool AesGcm::OpenAlgorithmProvider(BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE& hBC, const TCHAR* provider, const TCHAR* chaining_mode) {
    DWORD dwStatus = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hBC, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, provider, 0x0);
    if (FAILED(dwStatus)) {
        std::cout << "BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //std::wstring cc_mode(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM);
    //std::vector<uint8_t> bmode_bys(cc_mode.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) + 2);
    //std::memcpy(bmode_bys.data(), cc_mode.data(), bmode_bys.size());

    //dwStatus = BCryptSetProperty(hBC, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, bmode_bys.data(), bmode_bys.size() - 2, 0x0);
    //if (FAILED(dwStatus)) {
    //  std::cout << "BCryptSetProperty(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]" << std::endl;
    //  return false;
    //}

    dwStatus = BCryptSetProperty(hBC, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM), 0x0);
    if (FAILED(dwStatus)) {
        std::cout << "BCryptSetProperty(FAILED)::[0x" << std::hex << dwStatus << "]" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> AesGcm::GetProperty(BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE& hCH, const TCHAR* prop_name) {
    DWORD sz_1 = 0;//BCRYPT_AUTH_TAG_LENGTH / BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH
    DWORD dwStatus = BCryptGetProperty(hCH, prop_name, NULL, 0, &sz_1, 0x0);

    if (FAILED(dwStatus) || sz_1 <= 0)
        throw std::exception("BCryptGetProperty failed");

    std::vector<uint8_t> prop_bys(sz_1);
    dwStatus = BCryptGetProperty(hCH, prop_name, (PBYTE)prop_bys.data(), prop_bys.size(), &sz_1, 0x0);
    if (FAILED(dwStatus))
        throw std::exception("BCryptGetProperty failed2");

    return prop_bys;
}
```

- Changing from `std::vector` to `HeapAlloc`
- Changing around the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` a bit
- Changing the params for `BCryptSetProperty`
- Using well written version in C++ from GitHub Pages
- Trying 4+ fifferent ways of the code, including using Chat Bot GPT

Comment: Warning. You've likely been sucked in by a misleading bit of advice in the stackoverflow documentation folks have been screaming about for at least the almost-decade I've been on the site. Do NOT delete and re-ask questions with improvements. Prefer to fix up the initial question. You now have a deleted, negative-scored question serving as deadweight because the server takes deleted questions into account when it computes how long before you can ask a your next question. If this question isn't well received, it and the deleted question near-duplicate will both serve as anchors slowing you down

Comment: @user4581301 im the worst there is Im aware, I just a have a simple issue I need help on. Sorry about deleting the other one give me negative million rep I am fine with that . I just need help on this I wont delete anymore just make edits. I wont delete anymore, I made this one as simple as I can .

Comment: Error `0xC000000D` is `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The only difference between your 1st and 2nd call to `BCryptDecrypt()` is that the 2nd call is using `p_text` in the output parameters, so it stands to reason that the problem is related to your use of `p_text`.

Comment: what's `LocalFree` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm afraid I don't understand, we pass through NULL & 0 Params for the first call to get the size, note 0 is the size of the buffer the arg before that is NULL is the buffer, and pTextSize is the OUT param for the size. Once we make that call we out the data to that DWORD we then Call once more , but with the allocated Buffer of the pTextSize and instead of 0 I put "p_text.size()" as it wont make a difference if its "pTextSize" or "p_text.size()" as they are both the same, it also cant be referenced since it doesn't output it , it takes it in ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre note I dont provide full code as some said its too much but if you want the rest of the Functions I can update my post

Comment: @RemyLebeau i kinda understand now, but even when I HeapAlloc (most people do) it dosnt seem to change least I can try again, and the second param that was set to '0' well you cant mess that one up much , its a Integer not had to represent an Int so that param is correct :( I will try HeapAlloc instead of "p_text.data()" I also did look into the function , not just the parameters that can return that status code, if "cbSize" in the AUTH struct is smaller than 12 or bigger than 16 it will return "0xC000000D"

Comment: Are you sure you're using an authenticated encryption mode? That fourth parameter takes various things based on `dwFlags` (i.e. the last parameter).

Comment: @Spencer to be entirely sure, no im not sure , in the C# version of this , it uses that struct if there is an alternative I would be more than glad to use that OFC it actually decrypts that data I provided, last param they set it to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will leave this up for the future of people, I started to look into padding given this post [BCryptEncrypt returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER on AES-GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812848/bcryptencrypt-returns-status-invalid-parameter-on-aes-gcm)

I created a vector with X amount of Bytes , Copied the BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO ovver using memcpy based off the static X size

I see no padding least that will cut off / malformed the data, but I do see a value that keeps changing each debug at the end of the struct that seems to keep changing each run. I cast it back over to the trust seeing if its malformed or anything it seems fine. I do notice a field in the debugger though that I did not touch called "dwFlags" , it has a random value it sets to each run.

Set:

BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO.dwFlags = 0;

Problem Fixed :D

It was also mentioned in comments about "dwFlags" but I am assuming he meant the function signature not the structure if not then I assumed wrong. Either way problem fixed !